# Count of rows where the year is the current one

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to run this query in SQL Server Compact

```
SqlCeCommand saldo = new SqlCeCommand("select count(*) from objetos where year(datarececao) = getdate()", con);
Int32 count5 = (Int32)saldo.ExecuteScalar();
label16.Text = Convert.ToString(count5);
```

But since this is a SQL/MySQL query I get an error that the function is not recognized by SQLCE

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Try use [`datepart`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173998(v=sql.110).aspx) function

Comment: @AleksAndreev thanks for the tip, will try

Comment: @RufusL What here would require a parameter?

Comment: @juharr Nothing, just too tired...removed that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
from objetos 
where DATEPART(year, datarececao) = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
```